# Add to view model from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 tables, `tblUsers` and `tblChat`.

tblUsers

```
[Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName]    NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[LastName]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[EmailAddress] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Username]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Password]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

tblChat

```
[Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[From]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[To]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Message]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[DateSent] DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
[Read]     BIT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

and I also have their respective DTOs:

UserDTO

```
[Table("tblUsers")]
public class UserDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

ChatDTO

```
[Table("tblChat")]
public class ChatDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("From")]
    public virtual UserDTO FromUsers { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("To")]
    public virtual UserDTO ToUsers { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `chat view model` which I use to retreive all the rows from the `tblChat` table which goes like so:

```
public class ChatVM
{
    public ChatVM()
    {
    }

    public ChatVM(ChatDTO row)
    {
        Id = row.Id;
        From = row.From;
        To = row.To;
        Message = row.Message;
        DateSent = row.DateSent;
        Read = row.Read;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that `ChatVM` is not enough, I need more properties in there based on the `users` table.

The `from` property is a uniqye username from the `users` table, I need 3 more properties in the `ChatVM` that contain the `from`'s id, name and lastname.

Basically something like the following (it is modified `ChatVM`)

```
public class ChatVM
{
    public ChatVM()
    {
    }

    public ChatVM(ChatDTO row)
    {
        Id = row.Id;
        From = row.From;
        To = row.To;
        Message = row.Message;
        DateSent = row.DateSent;
        Read = row.Read;
        FromId = ???;
        FromFirstName = ???;
        FromLastName = ???;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }

    public int FromId { get; set; }
    public string FromFirstName { get; set; }
    public string FromLastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a "1-1" connection between UserDTO and ChatDTO entities, and each ChatDTO object has references with 2 UserDTO objects through foreign keys FromUsers and ToUsers. Your ChatVM constructor accepts as input a ChatDTO object so what if you used the foreign keys properties to get access to other properties of UserDTO class?

e.g

```
        FromId = row.FromUsers.Id; //Also you can check if FromUsers property is null to avoid exceptions
        FromFirstName = row.FromUsers.FirstName ;
        FromLastName = row.FromUsers.LastName ;
```

Think that your foreign keys in fact implement a join between your tables, so through them you can have full access to the primary class.

Answer (score 0):

you should use like

```
public class alldata
{
public IEnumerable<tbl_chat> chatdata { get; set; }


public IEnumerable<tbl_user> chatdata { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how does this related to the question?!!